# Hola soy principiante en programación y no se cual es mi error, me aparece esto "error: orphaned case"

Tags: javascript, java, while, programación-funcional, programación-bajo-nivel

[image: No entiendo porque me aparece este error alguien me puede ayudar]

Hola soy principiante en programación y no se cual es mi error, me aparece esto "error: orphaned case"

Comment: Por favor, lee [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y realiza el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas y aprendas como utilizar de manera correcta de usar el sitio. Luego, edita la pregunta para que se ajuste a las directivas de la comunidad. El título de la pregunta debe ser significativo y concreto y el código no se adjunta en imágenes.

Comment: En cuanto a tu "IDE", te conviene por tu propio beneficio mostrar al menos los números de líneas, ya que el compilador te ayuda bastante especificándose la línea de tu error. En este caso nunca declaraste el `switch`, por lo que los `case` están totalmente fuera de contexto. Otro error que tendrás después es que `scanner.next()` te devuelve un string, mientras que tus `case` los estás trabajando con enteros. O usas algo como `nextInt()` o, parseas manualmente o  usa `case "1":`.  Te recomiendo usar un IDE más moderno como `IntelliJ Community` o `Eclipse`.

Answer (score 1):

El error es simple, escribiste **while** en vez de **switch**, por otra parte añadiste un ***;*** después del paréntesis de cierre en la misma instrucción, no tienes que hacerlo cuando declaras un switch, un bucle, una condicional o una función ¡recuerda estudiar más!.